# Не видит массив в store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

Пытаюсь прикрутить MobX и столкнулся с проблемой: вылетает ошибка, мол массива, который я хочу обработать - его нет, хотя он очень даже есть.

Вот код:

**Topvisor.js** *(path: src/components/Topvisor/index.js)*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import Store from '../../store'

import './Topvisor.css';

@observer
class Topvisor extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    Store.getTopvisorData()
  }

  render() {
    if(Store.topvisorData.dataKeywords.lenth) {
      return (
        <div className="Topvisor">
          <h2>Topvisor</h2>
          <ul>
            {
              Store.topvisorData.dataKeywords.map(i => (
                <li key={i.id}>
                  <div className="topvisor__name">{i.name}</div>
                  <div className="topvisor__from-date">{i.positionsData['2018-06-30:561448:76'].position}</div>
                  <div className="topvisor__to-date">{i.positionsData['2018-07-04:561448:76'].position}</div>
                </li>
              ))
            }
          </ul>
        </div>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      )
    }
  }
}

export default Topvisor;
```

**store.js** *(path: src/store.js)*

```
import { observable, action } from 'mobx'

class Store {

  @observable topvisorData

  constructor() {
    this.topvisorData = {
      dataKeywords : [],
    }
  }

  @action('get Topvisor data')
  getTopvisorData() {
    fetch("https://api.topvisor.ru/v2/json/get/positions_2/history", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'User-Id'       : 'id',
        'Authorization' : 'token',
        'Content-type'  : 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        'group_folder_id_depth' : 1,
        'project_id'            : 561448,
        'regions_indexes'       : [76],
        'fields'                : ['name','id','tags','target','group_name'],
        'type_range'            : 2,
        'date1'                 : '2018-06-25',
        'date2'                 : '2018-07-04',
        'count_dates'           : 31,
        'limit'                 : 100,
        'offset'                : 0,
        'show_headers'          : 1,
        'show_exists_dates'     : 1,
        'show_visitors'         : 1,
        'show_top_by_depth'     : 10,
      })
    })
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
     })
    .then(data => {
      this.topvisorData.dataKeywords = data.result.keywords;
    });
  }
}

export default Store
```

Как это чинить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store - это класс, а значит, чтобы его использовать надо получить объект класса. Иначе просто не выполняется конструктор и вы вместо массива получаете undefined. И делать это лучше не в componentDidMount

Можно получить объект в конструкторе компонента:

```
@observer
class Topvisor extends Component {
    myStore;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.myStore = new Store;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.myStore.getTopvisorData();
    }

    ...
}
```

или задать константу:

```
const myStore = new Store;

@observer
class Topvisor extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        myStore.getTopvisorData();
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Идея правильная, но создавать экземпляр Store в компоненте категорически запрещено. Сколько у тебя будет таких экземпляров во всем приложении? Это противоречит принципу Single Data Store

Comment: Если - это корневой "компонент" - контейнер - почему нет? Для всех дочерних store будет single. Если, конечно, используется несколько компонентов, разбросанных по странице, то да

Comment: Если это корневой элемент, то можно. Но все равно лучше создать экземпляр класса в самом файле Store.js, чтобы ты импортил уже готовый экземпляр, а не class) Но тут уже вопрос удобства)

Comment: А если ему понадобится импортировать в нескольких разных модулях? Может случайно сделать несколько экземпляров store и не известно, к какому из них обратится. Тогда уж лучше синглтон сделать со статическим методом getStore

Comment: Ну обычно импортят не сам store, а actions с помощью которых получают или изменяю store) Ну, в общем, спор предлагаю закрыть, так как и то и то имеет место быть) Пора отправляться писать код, нет времени сидеть на stackoverflow ;)

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно лишь заэкспортить не `class` а экземпляр класса. `export default new Store()`

Создавать экземпляр класса в каждом компоненте запрещено! Должен быть 1 экземпляр на все приложение.

```js
import { observable, action } from 'mobx'

class Store {

  @observable topvisorData

  constructor() {
    this.topvisorData = {
      dataKeywords : [],
    }
  }

  @action('get Topvisor data')
  getTopvisorData() {
    fetch("https://api.topvisor.ru/v2/json/get/positions_2/history", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'User-Id'       : 'id',
        'Authorization' : 'token',
        'Content-type'  : 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        'group_folder_id_depth' : 1,
        'project_id'            : 561448,
        'regions_indexes'       : [76],
        'fields'                : ['name','id','tags','target','group_name'],
        'type_range'            : 2,
        'date1'                 : '2018-06-25',
        'date2'                 : '2018-07-04',
        'count_dates'           : 31,
        'limit'                 : 100,
        'offset'                : 0,
        'show_headers'          : 1,
        'show_exists_dates'     : 1,
        'show_visitors'         : 1,
        'show_top_by_depth'     : 10,
      })
    })
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
     })
    .then(data => {
      this.topvisorData.dataKeywords = data.result.keywords;
    });
  }
}
const store = new Store();
export default store;
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import { store } from '../../store'

import './Topvisor.css';

@observer
class Topvisor extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    store.getTopvisorData()
  }

  render() {
    if(store.topvisorData.dataKeywords.lenth) {
      return (
        <div className="Topvisor">
          <h2>Topvisor</h2>
          <ul>
            {
              store.topvisorData.dataKeywords.map(i => (
                <li key={i.id}>
                  <div className="topvisor__name">{i.name}</div>
                  <div className="topvisor__from-date">{i.positionsData['2018-06-30:561448:76'].position}</div>
                  <div className="topvisor__to-date">{i.positionsData['2018-07-04:561448:76'].position}</div>
                </li>
              ))
            }
          </ul>
        </div>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      )
    }
  }
}

export default Topvisor;
```

Comment: У меня и есть один экземпляр класса на все приложение - он лежит в App.js, а дальше пропсами прокидывается) Но все равно спасибо за ответ